# Apollo 2.0.0 Graphql cookie session

Tags: graphql, session-cookies, apollo-server, express-graphql

Can someone help me on this, My setup was as follows prior to Apollo 2.0, I had a server.js in which i used express and graphql-server-express
I had a http only cookie session, when a user logs in I set the jwt token as a cookie and it is set in browser as http only.
On subsequent request I validate the cookie that the browser passes back. It was all working fine and I could access
the token from req.session.token in any other resolver and validate the jwt token saved in the cookie session.

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'graphql-server-express';
import { ApolloEngine } from 'apollo-engine';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session';
import schema from './schema/';
​
const server = express();
​
server.use(
 cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: 'k1,k2',
  maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  domain: '.mydomain.com',
  path: '/',
 }),
);
​
const corsOptions = {
 origin: 'http://local.mydomain.com:3000',
 credentials: true,
 methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
};
​
server.use(cors(corsOptions));
​
server.use(
 '/graphql',
 bodyParser.json(),
 graphqlExpress(req => ({
  schema,
  tracing: true,
  context: { req },
 })),
);
​
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
 server.use('/graphiql',graphiqlExpress({endpointURL: '/graphql'}));
}
​
const engine = new ApolloEngine({
 apiKey: engineConfig.apiKey,
});
​
engine.listen(
 {
  port: 3000,
  graphqlPaths: ['/graphql'],
  expressApp: server,
 },
 () => {console.log('GraphiQL is now running');},
);
```

authenticateResolver.js

```
const authenticateResolver = {
 Query: {
  authenticate: async (root, args, context) => {
   const { req } = context;
​
   const auth = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${args.username}:${args.password}`).toString('base64')}`;
​
   const axiosResponse = await axios.post("localhot:8080/login, 'true', 
    {
     headers: {
       Authorization: auth,
     },
    });
​
   if (axiosResponse.status === 200 && axiosResponse.data.token) {
    req.session.token = axiosResponse.data.token;
   }
   return {
     status: 200,
   };
 },
```

But when I upgraded to Apollo 2.0 my server.js code changed, authenticateResolver was as is.
I am now unable to access req.session.token in any subsequent requests since the cookie session is not getting set.
When I open Developer tools in chrome I cannot see the cookie being set when Authentication is called.
What am I doing wrong here ?

server.js # After Apollo 2.0 upgrade 
​

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session';
import { mergedTypes, resolvers } from './schema/';
​
const server = express();
​
server.use(
 cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: 'k1,k2',
  maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  domain: '.mydomain.com',
  path: '/',
 }),
);
​
const corsOptions = {
 origin: 'http://local.mydomain.com:3000',
 credentials: true,
 methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
};
​
server.use(cors(corsOptions));
​
server.listen({ port: 3000 }, () => { 
 console.log('Server ready');
 console.log('Try your health check at: .well-known/apollo/app-health');
});
​
const apollo = new ApolloServer({
 typeDefs: gql`
  ${mergedTypes}
 `,
 resolvers,
 engine: false,
 context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
});
​
apollo.applyMiddleware({
 server
});
```

Comment: Did you get this working?  We are having the same issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, If you look at the graphql playground there is a settings option if you click on that you can observe few settings, one of them being
`"request.credentials": "omit"` just change it to
`"request.credentials": "include"` and save settings and it should now work.

[image: Refer to image]

My code looks as follows as well:

```js
const app = express()

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: corsConfig.cookieSecret.split(','),
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    domain: corsConfig.cookieDomain,
    path: '/',
  })
)

const corsOptions = {
  origin: corsConfig.corsWhitelist.split(','),
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql`
    ${mergedTypes}
  `,
  resolvers,
  engine: false,
  context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
  tracing: true,
  debug: !process.env.PRODUCTION,
  introspection: !process.env.PRODUCTION,
})

apollo.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/',
  cors: corsOptions,
})

app.listen({ port: engineConfig.port }, () => {
  console.log(' - Server ready')
  console.log('Try your health check at: .well-known/apollo/app-health')
})
```

Comment: Legend. I've no idea why default is set to omit. It did not occur for me to check that. Thanks !

Comment: Can you share your code for `corsConfig`?