# How to get req.user in ApolloServer

Tags: javascript, graphql, passport.js, google-oauth, apollo-server

What should I do to get req.user and req.logout and all the requests created in passport middleware in ApolloServer context. Just like I have access to it in

> app.get('/good', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => res.send(req.user));

I use cookie-session, paspport, passport-google-oauth20, express, apollo-server, express and cors packages

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  })
);

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: '/good',
  failureRedirect: '/fail',
}));


app.get('/good', (req, res) => res.send(req.user));

// route for logging out
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session = null;
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
  });


// Connect to Mongo(skipped)

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = require('./modules/graphqlschemas/index');
const resolvers = require('./modules/resolvers/index');


// #5 Initialize an Apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    getUser: () => {
      console.log(req.user);  // ! undefined !
    },
    logout: () => req.logout() // ! header not sent to the client error !
  })
});
```

Here's my googleAuth file:

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => done(err, user))
})
  
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const newUser = {
          googleId: profile.id,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          firstName: profile.name.givenName,
          lastName: profile.name.familyName,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
        }

        try {
          let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })

          if (user) {
            done(null, user)
          } else {
            user = await User.create(newUser)
            done(null, user)
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
    )
  )
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code away where you're calling `applyMiddleware`. It should be done after you add your session middleware.

Comment: Whatever, the problem was that ind graphql playground settings, credentials was set on omit by default. I just needed to change it. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977753/apollo-2-0-0-graphql-cookie-session/53055331#53055331 or directly here https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OU3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever, the problem was that in graphql playground settings, credentials was set on omit by default. I just needed to change it. Look here [Apollo 2.0.0 Graphql cookie session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977753/apollo-2-0-0-graphql-cookie-session/53055331#53055331) or directly here:

[image: code block]

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `req.user` into Apollo's context by creating a middleware for it after authentication with passport is done

```js
/// app.js

// you can move this to a new module for code brevity
const strategy = new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const newUser = {
          googleId: profile.id,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          firstName: profile.name.givenName,
          lastName: profile.name.familyName,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
        }

        try {
          let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })

          if (user) {
            done(null, user)
          } else {
            user = await User.create(newUser)
            done(null, user)
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
    )

passport.use(strategy)


// ...

const app = express()

// ...

passport.initialize()

app.use('/graphql', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (user) {
      req.user = user
    }

    next()
  })(req, res, next)
})

// ...
const typeDefs = require('./modules/graphqlschemas/index');
const resolvers = require('./modules/resolvers/index');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => {
   // do some other things with req

   // inject data into context like user
   return { user: req.user }
  }
})

server.applyMiddleware({
  app
})
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what he meant. Yes, you can retrieve `req.user` from `app.get` but not in graphql context

Comment: @AlanYong yes he did know what he meant. this is how it fixed for me as well. gotta set `user` before starting `server`.